# RMSE monthly or hourly according to month using apply with python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply

I have this dataframe:

```
dates,AA,BB,CC
2018-01-01 00:00:00,45.73,47.63,3.45625
2018-01-01 01:00:00,44.16,44.42,3.45625
2018-01-01 02:00:00,42.24,42.34,3.45625
2018-01-01 03:00:00,39.29,38.36,3.45625
2018-01-01 04:00:00,36,36.87,3.45625
2018-01-01 05:00:00,41.99,39.79,3.45625
2018-01-01 06:00:00,42.25,42.08,3.45625
2018-01-01 07:00:00,44.97,51.19,3.45625
2018-01-01 08:00:00,45,59.69,3.45625
2018-01-01 09:00:00,44.94,56.67,3.45625
2018-01-01 10:00:00,45.04,53.54,3.45625
2018-01-01 11:00:00,46.67,52.6,3.45625
2018-01-01 12:00:00,46.99,50.77,3.45625
2018-01-01 13:00:00,44.16,50.27,3.45625
2018-01-01 14:00:00,45.26,50.64,3.45625
2018-01-01 15:00:00,47.84,54.79,3.45625
2018-01-01 16:00:00,50.1,60.17,3.45625
2018-01-01 17:00:00,54.3,59.47,3.45625
2018-01-01 18:00:00,51.91,60.16,3.45625
2018-01-01 19:00:00,51.38,70.81,3.45625
2018-01-01 20:00:00,49.2,62.65,3.45625
2018-01-01 21:00:00,45.73,59.71,3.45625
2018-01-01 22:00:00,44.84,50.96,3.45625
2018-01-01 23:00:00,38.11,46.52,3.45625
2018-01-02 00:00:00,19.19,49.62,3.405
2018-01-02 01:00:00,14.99,45.05,3.405
2018-01-02 02:00:00,11,45.18,3.405
2018-01-02 03:00:00,10,37.12,3.405
2018-01-02 04:00:00,11.83,38.03,3.405
2018-01-02 05:00:00,14.99,46.17,3.405
2018-01-02 06:00:00,40.6,51.71,3.405
2018-01-02 07:00:00,46.99,54.37,3.405
2018-01-02 08:00:00,47.95,75.3,3.405
2018-01-02 09:00:00,49.9,68.48,3.405
2018-01-02 10:00:00,50,61.94,3.405
2018-01-02 11:00:00,49.7,63.26,3.405
2018-01-02 12:00:00,48.16,59.41,3.405
2018-01-02 13:00:00,47.24,60,3.405
2018-01-02 14:00:00,46.1,67.44,3.405
2018-01-02 15:00:00,47.6,66.82,3.405
2018-01-02 16:00:00,50.45,72.17,3.405
2018-01-02 17:00:00,54.9,70.28,3.405
2018-01-02 18:00:00,57.18,62.63,3.405
```

Basically, hourly date from 2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31.

I would like to do different things by means of apply method or equivalent.
First of all, I would like to compute the RMSE (root mean square error) at monthly scale between BB and CC with AA as reference solution.
I do this as follow:

```
dfr = dfr.assign(month=lambda x: x.index.month).groupby('month')
rmseBB = dfr.apply(rmse,   s1='AA',s2='BB')
rmseCC = dfr.apply(rmse,   s1='AA',s2='CC')
```

and here the rmse function:

```
def rmse(group,s1,s2):
    if len(group) == 0:
        return np.nan
    s = (group[s1] - group[s2]).pow(2).sum()
    print(len(group))
    rmseO = np.sqrt(s / len(group)) 
    return rmseO
```

The previous procedure seems to work properly as the given results.

In addition to that, I would like to do something a more complicate, at least according to my actual knowledge.

I would like to compute the RMSE for each hour belonging to the same month. I mean a RMSE for each first hour in January, a RMSE for each second hour in January, and so on. This will imply 24 value of RMSE for each month. After that I could compute the average hourly RMSE for each month. More important, I would like to be able to select the hours to consider in the average hourly RMSE.

This would imply a sort of double groupby, monthly and hourly. Am I wrong?

I hope to have made myself clear.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Diego

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Dates.csv")
year=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
time=list('0'+str(x) for x in range(10))+list(str(x) for x in range(11,24))
for i in year:
    df_mon=df[(df['dates'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[0][5:7])==i)]
    if len(df_mon)==0:
        continue
    for j in time:
        df_time=df_mon[(df_mon['dates'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[1][0:2])==j)]
        RMSE_BB=pow(pow(df_time['AA']-df_time['BB'],2).mean(),0.5)
        RMSE_CC=pow(pow(df_time['AA']-df_time['CC'],2).mean(),0.5)
        print(i,j,RMSE_BB, RMSE_CC)
```

Comment: Dear Pratik, thanks for you help. However, something is not clear to me. 1) I suppose year starts with 01 and ends with 12. 2) it is not clear what does it means time. why is there x in range(1,10) and then in range (11,24)? is this due to the number of hours? I have as results something between 01 and 23. Finally, what about the use of pd.index due to the fact that in all my dfr I have parse_dates=True. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Dedro, I have modified the code after noticing the mistake 01 to 12 are months in a year and 00 to 23 are hours in the codẹ. The given code gives you the RMSE of every month with every hour.

Comment: what about the use of  parse_dates? Could this avoid the use of split()[0][5:7])? Thanks again. Sorry for the question but these will help me in understanding and learn, Thanks again

Comment: split() will split the string in 2 parts here. Take example of "2018-01-02 08:00:00", split()[0] will take the first part of the output and then [5:7] will take the 5th and 6th character. In our example, split()[0] will take "2018-01-02" and then split()[0][5:7] will take 5 th and 6th characters as a string which is "01". This code will only help if the date is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: What about ".groupby"()? I would like to use that and to take advantage of dateindex.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use group by you can do like below.

```
import pandas as pd
def rmse(df_time):
    RMSE_BB=pow(pow(df_time['AA']-df_time['BB'],2).mean(),0.5)
    RMSE_CC=pow(pow(df_time['AA']-df_time['CC'],2).mean(),0.5)
    return RMSE_BB,RMSE_CC

df=pd.read_csv("Dates.csv")
df['month']=df['dates'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[0][5:7])
df['time']=df['dates'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1][0:2])
df1=df.groupby(['month','time']).apply(rmse)
df1
```